# Javascript Date Display in DatePicker

Tags: javascript, react-native, date

I have a response from the server as 01 Jun 2020. It Displays as a placeholder in DatePicker.
But I need to display it as 01/06/2020.

```
this.setState({ 
    start_date: responseJsonFromServer.start_date      
});
```

Here start_date is 01 Jun 2020. Need to convert as 01/06/2020. Please Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out MomentJS it is an easy package to use and it lets you format your date like you want.

```
const date = new Date();

const formattedDate = Moment(date).format("DD/MM/YY")
```

this will show you the desired format. Check out momentjs because it has some very cool features like adding and subtracting from that date for example.

https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Its working with moment.js. Thank you bro.                                                                                       Answer is                                                                                                               placeHolderText= { moment(this.state.start_date).format("DD/MM/YYYY")  }

Answer (score 0):

Send prop with format to your date picker:

```
format="DD/MM/YYYY"
```

Comment: In DataPicker Date display as that format.(After Date Pick).                                                                placeHolderText={ this.state.start_date } But I display Place holder as 01 jun 2020. I need to display as 01/06/2020

Comment: then try the answer @yesIamFaded